# Winforms WebBrowser tell when done Refreshing

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a page that refreshes every 20 seconds and I need to know when it is done refreshing, the DocumentCompleted event does not fire when you refresh for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Visual Basic doesn't have a WebBrowser control. .NET does.

Comment: @John, then why don't you just retag it?

Comment: @Matt: I did retag it, and I also changed the title, and I informed the OP so he doesn't do it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try waiting until the `WebBrowser.ReadyState` property is set to complete.  Alternatively, instead of `Refresh()`ing you could `Navigate()` to the current URL, which would cause the DocumentCompleted event to fire as you want.

Comment: But Navigate() does not get the new page, it simply gets it from the cache if it has loaded it before. Also what is the wait function in Visual Basic?

Comment: @Bubby: Try something similar to while WebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

Comment: Does sleep not halt the thread? Other things will need to run.